# In android FlashLight and SOS FlashLight is not working together

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build a Flashlight app with SOS features. Both features are working individually. But when I want to start the flashlight blinking it blinks but didn't work smoothly. Suppose :
Case 1: If I progress the seek bar flash starts to blinking that's good but if I want to change the seek bar progress during the Flash blinking, progress act like frizzed.

Case 2: during flash blinking, I can't stop the flash immediately.

Case 3: Individually both are working.

I have used threading for blinking the Flashlight. I am giving some code below. My motive is to build a flashlight with an SOS feature.

```
//When progress seekbar for SOS Flashlight
private void seekbarFunc(int val) {
        String myString = "010101010101010101";
        long blinkDelay = val + 500; //Delay in ms


        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

            }
        }).start();

        for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
            if (myString.charAt(i) == '0') {
                Utilities.startFlashlight(this, mPreference);

            } else {
                Utilities.stopFlashlight(this, mPreference);
            }
            try {
                thread.sleep(blinkDelay);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

// FlashLlight turned on by this method
    private static boolean flashLightOn(Context context) {
        try {
            if (mCameraManager == null) {
                initCameraManagerInstance(context);
            }
            String cameraId = mCameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            mCameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);
            // Sending broadcast to update the UI
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(new Intent(ACTION_UPDATE_UI));
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "flashLightOn(): " + e);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

//FlashLight turned off by this method
private static boolean flashLightOff(Context context) {
        try {
            if (mCameraManager == null) {
                initCameraManagerInstance(context);
            }
            String cameraId = mCameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            mCameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, false);
            // Sending broadcast to update the UI
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(new Intent(ACTION_UPDATE_UI));
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "flashLightOff(): " + e);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```